# Function is executed before the other one, but it should be the other way round?

Tags: node.js

I'm learning mongodb and nodejs at the moment. This is my code:

```
var databaseUrl = "mydb";
var collections = ["users", "reports"];
var db = require("mongojs").connect(databaseUrl, collections);

safeuser = function() {
    db.users.save(
        {
            email: "john@example.com",
            password: "iLoveMongo",
            sex: "male"
        },
        function( error, saved) {
            if( error || !saved )
                console.log( "User not saved");
            else 
                console.log( "User saved" );
        }
    );
};

finduser = function() {
    db.users.find(
        {
            sex: "male"
        },
        function(error, users) {
            if( error || !users.length )
                console.log( "No male Users found");
            else 
            {
                console.log( "male Users found" );
                users.forEach(
                    function(maleUser) {
                        console.log(maleUser);
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    )
};

safeuser( null, finduser() );
```

What I want to do is execute finduser() after safeuser(). What I get is:

```
22 May 21:21:14 - [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
No male Users found
User saved
```

finduser() is executed before safeuser(). I thought in the last line of code I set finduser() to be the callback function of safeuser()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently you are invoking the finduser function immediately when `safeuser(null, finduser());` is run.

You need to pass the reference to the function `finduser` and then invoke it (with `()`) inside of your `safeuser` function for it to work in sync.

try this:

```
var databaseUrl = "mydb";
var collections = ["users", "reports"];
var db = require("mongojs").connect(databaseUrl, collections);

saveUser = function(user, cb) {
  db.users.save(user, function(error, saved) {
      if( error || !saved )
        console.log( "User not saved");
      else 
        console.log( "User saved" );
        return cb("male");
    }
  );
};

findUser = function(gender) {
  db.users.find({ sex: gender }, function(error, users) {
      if( error || !users.length ) {
        console.log( "No male Users found");
      } else {
        console.log( "male Users found" );

        users.forEach(function(maleUser) {
          console.log(maleUser);
        });

      }
    }
  )
};

newUser = {
            email: "john@example.com",
            password: "iLoveMongo",
            sex: "male"
          };

saveUser(newUser, findUser);
```

notice that finduser is passed into saveUser as a reference. Then it is returned with `cb()` inside saveUser.

[image: puddingproof]

Answer (score 0):

For serial execution you can use nimble lib http://caolan.github.io/nimble/ . It is great simplify you code logic.

```
var _ = require('nimble');

//...

newUser = {
        email: "john@example.com",
        password: "iLoveMongo",
        sex: "male"
};

_.series([
    function (callback) {
       saveUser(newUser, function(err, data){
         callback();
       });
    },
    function (callback) {
       findUser();
       callback();
    }
]);
```